# Is suexec function stable in apache prefork module?

Tags: apache, centos, suexec

My server enviroment: centos 6.4, apache2.2 with prefork module, php 5.3 with module 5.c.
i have 10 vitualhosts run by apache, i want to seperate these 10 sites, can i use suexec function in my server? is suexec reliable in my production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it executes something which can be slow, because it needs to start a new process for every query.

This problem can be solved by the fcgi.

A much better solution were if you used mpm-itk ( http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/ ) works like the prefork mpm, but with itk you can define different users/groups for your virtualhosts in the main apache config. There is no need for any setuid or such tricks.

Comment: in php official manual, it recommend to use prefork module apache.even in centos, yum install apache is prefork module. i am not expert, i doubt mpm-itk,fastcgi is not stable like prefork. is that true? I just want a stable, safe server.

Comment: mpm-itk is an unofficial variant of the prefork mpm, and in my experience it is exactly so stable. Your books are suggesting prefork against the worker or other thread-based mpms, which are much better but not so stable. But mpm-itk is exactly so fork-based as the prefork.